# Minimize sum of products of partition

Tags: discrete-optimization

I have a set of positive integer numbers $A = \{a_1,\dots,a_N\}$ and I need to find a partition of $A$ into two sets, such that the sum of their products is minimal, i.e.,
$$
 \min_{X,Y : X \cup Y = A} \prod_{x \in X} x + \prod_{y \in Y} y.
$$
Is there any good approximation/heuristic algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: May we assume the numbers are distinct (since it's a set of numbers)? Are the numbers reals, integers, nonnegative integers, positive integers...?

Comment: Let's assume distinct (would be nice if it worked without), and positive integers.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152673/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4480170/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an upper bound by instead minimizing $$2\max\left(\prod_{x\in X} x, \prod_{x\in A \setminus X} x\right).$$ Equivalently, minimize $$\max\left(\sum_{x\in X} \log x, \sum_{x\in A \setminus X} \log x\right),$$ which you can linearize as follows.  Let binary decision variable $s_a$ indicate whether $a \in X$, and let continuous decision variable $z$ represent the maximum of the two sums of logs. The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
z &\ge \sum_{a\in A} (\log a) s_a \\
z &\ge \sum_{a\in A} (\log a)(1 - s_a)
\end{align}

---

See https://oeis.org/A127180 for optimal values for the original problem when $A=\{1,\dots,n\}$.  The resulting sum of products $$\prod_{a\in A: s_a=1} a + \prod_{a\in A: s_a = 0} a$$ obtained from solving the linearized problem agrees with the optimal values found there.